# FIle Upload with response in Portlet For IBM

Tags: java, ajax, portlet, websphere-portal

**What needs to be Achieved:**
I have been trying to Find a way to Upload file and send response with a Json if it is Successful in IBM Websphere Portlet  using AJAX

**How i was able to do Some Part of it:**
I was able to Upload the file using ActionURL but in Action i was not able to Find a way to Send response from ActionMapping

**Approach needed:**
I know we can send response using ResourceMapping but i am not able to find a way to upload A file on Resouce Mapping

> Working Code For File Upload Which needs to be updated for Recieving Response in AJAX
>
> **JSP**
>
> ```
> <form:form method="POST" 
> modelAttribute="uploadForm" 
> enctype="multipart/form-data">
>   <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo"/>
>  <button tabindex="2" type="submit" name="Next" value="Upload" id="Next" >Next</button>
> </form:form>
> ```
>
> **Code:For IBM Portlet**
>
> ```
> @ActionMapping(params="file=processUploadedFile")
>    public void processUploadedFileNew(@RequestParam("logo") MultipartFile file,
>           final  ActionRequest request,final ActionResponse response) throws IOException {
> //I was able to Handle Code here
>       }
> ```

However with Above code i want to change request to AJAX and no reload of page is Desired so i need to change the Action to Resource.

**Note:**
I am known to the technique where u can send parameters from ActionMapping to RenderMapping and send back data in ModelAndView but this is not desired as i want the response back in AJAX Success Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution . Please see below solution using the Jar

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext;

Code
@ResourceMapping(value = "uploadfile")
    public void processUploadedFile(final ResourceRequest request, final ResourceResponse response, final PortletRequest portletRequest){

HttpServletRequest originalHttpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) (com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portlet.PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(request));
        final boolean multipartContent = FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(new ServletRequestContext(originalHttpServletRequest));

        if (multipartContent) {
            file= createPEService.getResourceToBeUploaded(originalHttpServletRequest,file,bytes);
        }
}
```

Jsp File:

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="uploadfile"
    var="uploadfile" />

  <form class="testClass" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     </form>
```

JS:

```
isMultipart = 'multipart/form-data' === referenceForm.enctype,
 var $referenceForm = $( e.currentTarget ).parents( 'form' ),
                        referenceForm = $referenceForm.get( 0 ),
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: ${uploadfile},
                    processData: ! ( isMultipart ),
                    contentType: isMultipart ? false : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    data: isMultipart ? new FormData( referenceForm ) : $referenceForm.serialize(),
                    cache: false
                }).done(function( data ) {
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are trying to do will work because of portlets two phase rendering process.

Two suggestions either use the old single portlet refresh and send back json data(still cannot change the data type on that response though)

or use a separate servlet you package with the portlet and send it through that